# why does an error occur in this code?

Tags: android, json

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView fruitsList;
String url = "http://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/example_data/fruits_array.json";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fruitsList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.fruitsList);

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String string) {
            parseJsonData(string);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some error occurred!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    rQueue.add(request);
}

void parseJsonData(String jsonString) {
    try {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray fruitsArray = object.getJSONArray("fruits");
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

        for(int i = 0; i < fruitsArray.length(); ++i) {
            al.add(fruitsArray.getString(i));
        }

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al);
        fruitsList.setAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

some error occurred!! appears whenever i run it. can someone tell me where i gone wrong in this code? i'm a beginner and going through some revisions from my sch work. cant seem to get this to work

Comment: Can you be more specific? What kind of error? What errors areshowing? What line number where it occurs?

Comment: If `"some error occurred"`, there must be `"some reason causing it"`. Which is most likely described in your ***logcat***.

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain more verbose error output, you need to access the exception and print what you need from there. In this case, you insist on using a toast (you shouldn't, you should log the error directly to console with the Log class, in this case Log.e(ex.getMessage());)

Try the following;

```
 @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```